# Where has JSBin been installed?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I wanted to follow [this page](https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/blob/master/docs/running-your-own-jsbin.md) to run JSBin locally.

I just installed `xcode 8.2` in my mac. Now, `npm -v` returns `3.10.9`; `node -v` returns `v7.2.1`. `npm install` returns

```
/Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin$ npm install

> jsbin@3.40.2 postinstall /Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin
> grunt build && npm run selenium:install

Running "concat:dist" (concat) task
File "public/js/prod/jsbin-3.40.2.js" created.

Running "concat:runner" (concat) task
File "public/js/prod/runner-3.40.2.js" created.

Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
File "public/js/prod/jsbin-3.40.2.min.js" created.

Running "uglify:runner" (uglify) task
File "public/js/prod/runner-3.40.2.min.js" created.

Running "uglify:embed" (uglify) task
File "public/js/embed.min.js" created.

Running "uglify:addons" (uglify) task
File "public/js/prod/addon-tern-3.40.2.min.js" created.

Done, without errors.

> jsbin@3.40.2 selenium:install /Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin
> selenium-standalone install

----------
selenium-standalone installation starting
----------

---
selenium install:
from: https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.53/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
to: /Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-server/2.53.1-server.jar
---
chrome install:
from: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/chromedriver_mac64.zip
to: /Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/chromedriver/2.25-x64-chromedriver
---
firefox install:
from: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.11.1/geckodriver-v0.11.1-macos.tar.gz
to: /Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/geckodriver/0.11.1-x64-geckodriver
---
File from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.25/chromedriver_mac64.zip has already been downloaded
---
File from https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.53/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar has already been downloaded
---
File from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.11.1/geckodriver-v0.11.1-macos.tar.gz has already been downloaded


-----
selenium-standalone installation finished
-----

> jsbin@3.40.2 prepublish /Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin
> npm run snyk-protect


> jsbin@3.40.2 snyk-protect /Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin
> snyk protect

Successfully applied Snyk patches
```

It seems that `jsbin` has been installed, however, I could not find it under `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/`.

Does anyone know where it is?

**Edit 1:** `npm start` returns:

```
/Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin$ npm start

> jsbin@3.40.2 start /Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin
> (sleep 2 && open http://localhost:3000) & ./bin/jsbin

Config from /Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin/lib/config.local.json
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v51-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)

npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.2.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! jsbin@3.40.2 start: `(sleep 2 && open http://localhost:3000) & ./bin/jsbin`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the jsbin@3.40.2 start script '(sleep 2 && open http://localhost:3000) & ./bin/jsbin'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the jsbin package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     (sleep 2 && open http://localhost:3000) & ./bin/jsbin
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs jsbin
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls jsbin
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/softtimur/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin/npm-debug.log
```

Additionally, I think `.bin/jsbin` it runs is what has been inside the git folder; it was not built by my `npm install`.

Comment: Run `npm start` inside `/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could not find it under /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/

That is to be expected, because you copied the package repo to `~/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin`, for use in *development*, as opposed to using `npm install -g jsbin` to install it *globally*, for *regular use*.

Using `npm start` from `~/Startup/WebProjects/jsbin`, as Benjamin suggests, is the right approach.

`npm start` *does* find the `jsbin` executable, namely in *subfolder* `./bin` (if you look in `package.json`, key `"scripts"`, you'll see line
`"start": "(sleep 2 && open http://localhost:3000) & ./bin/jsbin"`).

The error message you're getting is actually generated by `jsbin` itself, indicating a problem with the package's *installation*.

Comment: It seems that `npm install` did not succeed to generate `jsbin`, though there was no error there. I re-cloned it, and it raised [an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254302/uncaught-exception-in-node-pre-gyp-install-fallback-to-build) during `npm install` as what we got from `npm start` here.

Comment: @SoftTimur: Understood. If you haven't already done so, I suggest you also raise an issue [at the source repo](https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/issues).

Comment: I see... But I don't know if it is my problem (eg, configuration) or the problem of the source code...

Comment: @SoftTimur: Good point. I suggest reading through the open issues - of which there are many. I cloned the repo myself and got plenty of warnings re obsolete versions and compilation errors - the repo may not have seen an update in a while.